# Symfony @ParamConverter: exclude the use if the placeholder does not contain a dot

Tags: php, symfony

I have this controller:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @Route("entity/{domain_host}")
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="AppBundle:Entity", options={
 *     "repository_method" = "findOneByDomainHost",
 *     "mapping": {"domain_host": "domainHost"},
 *     "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
class EntityController extends Controller
{
...
}
```

This way an URL like `http://example.com/entity/another-example.com` is matched by the action and the corresponding `another-example.com` entity is hydrated and passed to the controller.

Now, this entity has also an ID.

I'd like to intercept an URL like `http://example.com/entity/12345` and redirect it to `http://example.com/entity/another-example.com`.

To do this I created another method in the `EntityController`:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @Route("entity/{domain_host}")
 * @ParamConverter("store", class="AppBundle:Entity", options={
 *     "repository_method" = "findOneByDomainHost",
 *     "mapping": {"domain_host": "domainHost"},
 *     "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
class EntityController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectIdToDomainAction(Request $request)
    {
        die(dump($request));
        // Following will be the redirect logic
    }
}
```

And in my `routing.yml`, AT THE TOP OF THE FILE:

```
entity_id_to_domain:
    path: /entity/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Entity:redirectIdToDomain }
    requirements:
        id: ^[^.]*$
    methods: [GET]
```

Practically the `redirectIdToDomain` action is called if the placeholder doesn't contain a dot (the dot is the discrimen: if the placeholder has a dot, a domain is passed, if there isn't the dot, the placeholder probably represents an Entity by uts ID and I have to redirect).

The problem is that, as the controller class `EntityController` uses the `@ParamConverter` the placeholder is ever interpreted as a domain and the consequence is that I get a `AppBundle:Entity object not found.`.

So, is there a way to apply the `@ParamConverter` only if the placeholder has a dot? Or, which other approaches can I use to make the `redirectToIdAction` work without throwing the `Not found` exception?

Comment: better implements a listener for the redirect stuff and/or a custom paramconverter

Comment: Why not put the paramconverter on the one action that requires it instead of the class, or move your redirect action outside of it?

Comment: The `paramconverter` is required by more actions (about 7). I thought about the possibility to move the redirect action out of the class, but I hoped there were another options, so asked here... Instead of creating a custom param converter I think I'll create another controller and in it I will put the redirect action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom ParamConverter might do the trick, but if you don't want to make one, you will have to use different routes for IDs and domain names.

## Solution 1

Since your routing is done on the whole class and not on the actions themselves, I'm afraid you will have to move the redirect action to another controller class.

After that, you can match IDs and domain names selectively using requirements

```
/**
 *@Route(
    "entity/{domain_host}",
     name="entity_domain",
     requirements={"domain_host": "^(?=.*[\w])(?=.*[.]).+$"}
 *)
 *@ParamConverter(...)
 */
someActionOnDomainAction()
{
//...
}


/**
 *@Route(
    "entity/{id}",
     name="entity_domain",
     requirements={"id": "^[\d]$"}
 *)
 */
redirectIdToDomainAction()
{
//...
}
```

## Solution 2

Alternatively, you could change you repository method `findOneByDomainHost()` to something like `findOneByDomainHostOrID()`, and make it match both domain names and numeric IDs.

This way you get rig of `Object Not Found` errors, and you can always get the domain name of your entity, and do the redirection in the same controller action.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Class EntityController
 *
 * @Route("/entity/{domain_host}", name="domain_host")
 * @ParamConverter("domain_host", class="AppBundle:Entity", options={
 *     "repository_method" = "findOneByHostOrID"
 * })
 */
class EntityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="show_domain_host")
     * @param Entity $domain_host
     */
    public function domain_hostAction(Entity $domain_host, Request $request)
    {
        $id = $domain_host->getId();
        $host = $domain_host->getHost();

        // Get the unconverted route parameter.
        $parameter = $request->attributes->get('_route_params')['domain_host'];

        if ($parameter == $domain_host->getId()){
            // If the route parameter matches the ID,
            // redirect to the same route using the domain host.
            $url = $this->generateUrl('show_mail', ['mail' => $lib]);
            return $this->redirect($url, 301);
        }

        return new Response("<html><body>$id $host</body></html>");
    }
}
```

And the repository class:

```
class EntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneByHostOrID($domain_host)
    {
        if (preg_match("[\\d]",$domain_host)) {
            return $this->findOneById($domain_host);
        } else {
            return $this->findOneByHost($domain_host);
        }
    }
}
```